# how to send a body from a textarea from a .js page to a .php page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, email, textarea

I've been looking all over StackOverflow and other forum sites, but I still don't know how to acomplish what I'm doing.

I want to send personalized emails (can be text or html) in a website I'm developing.

I'm using ajax to send the list of mails, the subject and the body. The code looks like this

This is the .js

```
    function loadsentmail(){

var subject = document.getElementById("subject_title").value;
var content = tinyMCE.get('content').getContent();
var from = "somemail@mail.com";
var body = new Array();
body[0]=content;
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:'sendmail.php?mails='+mails+'&names='+names+'&idgroup='+idGrupo+'&subject='+subject+'&body='+body+'&from='+from+'&flag=1',
data: {},
            success:function(result){

                alert("Mail sent correctly");
                },
            error:function(){
                alert("Mail was not sent");
            }
});
}
```

This is the .php

```
$to = $_GET['mails'];
$names = $_GET['names'];
$subject=$_GET['subject'];
$from = $_GET['from'];
$body = $_GET['body'];
$flag=$_GET['flag'];
$groupId=$_GET['idgroup'];
echo $flag;
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: Some Company <somemail@somemail.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: somemail@somemail.com\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-path: somemail@somemail.com\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Cc: somemail@somemail.com\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Bcc: somemail@somemail.com\r\n";
switch($flag)
{
case 1:
    if (mail($to, $subject,$body,$headers)) {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} 
    else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
    }
break;
}
```

So far so good, I tested with small body, and it worked, but once I pasted a big html file, I got the following error

```
<h1>Request-URI Too Large</h1>
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.<br />
</p>
```

What is the best practice to send a big Body from a .js to a .php?? I've search a lot throughout the internet but I still can find an answer. Please help me :S

Comment: Instead of sending the data on url string send it as an object in the data property as it is intended. Then set it to send Post rather than get.

Comment: Also, the querystring is more limited in the amount of data it can store, therefore the data is being truncated.  Switch to Posting the data as suggested in the first comment.

Comment: Could you attach a simple example that I can follow?I'm sorry but I'm a very beginner programmer. I've learned all I know in my way, so I would appreciate a little push hehe

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
 type:'POST',
 url:'sendmail.php',
 data: {
  mails: mails,
  names: names,
  idgroup: idGrupo,
  subject: subject,
  body: body,
  from: from,
  flag:1
 },
 type: "POST",
 success:function(result){

    alert("Mail sent correctly");
 },
 error:function(){
    alert("Mail was not sent");
  }
});
```

Post will allow the larger data set and with jquery ajax you should send the data using the data object even if you use GET.

Also I believe (I'm a perl not a php dev so you will need to look this up) you will need to change your php to grab from the Post obj.
`$to = $_GET['mails'];` will become `$to = $_POST['mails']`

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it worked! Its now sending the data properly. However I'm not sure if the .php is receiving the data properly. I have to use $_POST instead of $_GET to access those elements?

Comment: haha I didn't see the last part! I'm sorry! It works perfectly now. THANKS!